# PhoneGap app with logic completely on remote web server

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am compiling an app on PhoneGap. All application logic is on the server.

I tried to do:
Inside app index.html have the boot screen and onDeviceReady use:

```
$ (': mobile-pagecontainer'). pagecontainer ('change', 'http://example.com/mobile-app/', {
    transition: 'slide',
    changeHash: false,
    showLoadMsg: true,
    role: "page",
});
```

Where http://example.com/mobile-app/ is mobile pages with full logic of app.

To jqm opened a page before loading it do:

```
$ (document) .bind ("mobileinit", function () {
    $ .mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
    $ .mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $ .support.cors = true;
});
```

Yes, it is loaded, but ignores all loaded libraries on a new page, I am unable to make a $ .mobile.ajaxEnabled = false, and so on. I think it's not a perfect solution. Maybe can fully reset index.html of the app with content of http://example.com/mobile-app/index.html ?

And how should the application be created on PhoneGap, resources which completely outside?

Comment: Read #5 of [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: Thanks! Ok, i understand all libraries only in app it is not problem. But I can not reinstall the app often, so I want to move all the logic on the server to make changes without recompiling and reinstalling app. How to do it correctly?

Comment: Take a look at hot code push strategies, there's a plugin for that https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push

Comment: @Mark, if you want to learn Phonegap you can use [Phonegap Desktop App](http://app.phonegap.com/) (works with CLI) _OR_ Phonegap Build with Hydratron. Hydration is available on your control panel for your app.